# how to access the next node in c++?

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I need to solve the following question: "Delete Middle Node: Implement an algorithm to delete a node in the middle (Le., any node but
the first and last node, not necessarily the exact middle) of a singly linked list, given only access to
that node.
EXAMPLE
Input: the node c from the linked list a - >b- >c - >d - >e- >f
Result: nothing is returned, but the new linked list looks like a->b->d->e->f".

Now, that is the solution im trying to implement:
"In this problem, you are not given access to the head of the linked list. You only have access to that node.
The solution is simply to copy the data from the next node over to the current node, and then to delete the
next node."

How can I write that in c++, having only iterators and no next() method? I need to do only one operation on a single node, with no need to iterate over the whole list, so I must be missing something... Do c++'s iterators let me solve it this way?

Comment: You're asking here too soon, I'm afraid. The best advice I can give at this point is draw a lot of pictures to help you visualize what the list needs to look like before, during, and after each operation. The changes you need to make to the picture in each stage of the list operation will be analogous to what the code must do. Even better, when it comes time to debug, and you will have to debug, you'll have a bunch of pictures you can use with a debugger to help spot where the program deviates from the expected - usually a bug.

Comment: Do you know how Linked List is, typically, defined? Do you know what it is? is there any [mcve], you can provide?

Comment: Removed the stl tag, as it has nothing to do with STL.

Comment: @Jarod42 "_you might copy value from node to node._" This is exactly what's stated in the problem, which is provided in the question: "_The solution is simply to copy the data from the next node over to the current node, and then to delete the next node._" The OP is asking "_how to access the next node_", though.

Comment: You should at least post the provided Node struct. And the code you wrote so far.

Comment: OP, you HAVE to have a next pointer in a linked list. Its not a function, but it wouldn't be a linked list if there was no pointer `next` to the next node.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple. The function can look the following way

```
// The structure definition is only for exposition.
struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node *next;
};

void delete_middle( Node *node )
{
    Node *tmp = node->next;

    node->value = node->next->value;
    node->next  = node->next->next;

    delete tmp;
}
```

It does not check whether `node` points to the first or the last node of the list according to your description.

> an algorithm to delete a node in the middle (Le., **any node but the
>   first and last node**, not necessarily the exact middle) of a singly
>   linked list,

If you are dealing with iterators then the function can be defined the following way. Let's assume that the type of the iterator is defined like `list::iterator`

```
void delete_middle( list::iterator it )
{
    auto next = std::next( it );

    it->value = next->value;
    it->next  = next->next;

    delete next;
}
```

But it depends on how the iterator is defined.

Comment: @rcgldr Pointers are a kind of iterators.:)

Comment: Question is a bit too confused to answer at this point, but the end result will probably look something like this.

Answer (score 0):

> Do c++'s iterators let me solve it this way?

No, the erase function will need low level access to the node members, such as data and next. A "standard C++ iterator" doesn't have an iterator::erase() function. You could create your own custom iterator class, specific to your single linked list class. You could include get and set functions to your custom iterator class in order to access the next pointer of an element (I'm not sure if this violates the intent of using an iterator). I assume that dereferencing an iterator (*iterator) would be used to access the data, the same as a "standard C++ iterator".

STL has a std::list::erase(std::list::iterator) function, but that has low level access to both the list (the container) and the iterator (an iterator to an element of the container).

---

Follow up - the differences between a pointer and an iterator. In the case of a pointer, dereferencing a pointer accesses whatever the pointer is pointed to, while dereferencing an iterator accesses only the data portion of the element that the iterator is pointed to. Using a double linked list element as an example:

```
    struct Node
    {   // list node
        Node * Next;      // ptr to next node
        Node * Prev;      // ptr to prev node
        long   Data;      // data
    };

    *pointer_to_node  ... // accesses entire struct

    *iterator_to_node ... // equivalent to pointer_to_node->Data
```

Comment: Sorry but this is just incorrect. A pointer is a type of iterator, and it is all you need to accomplish this task. Copy the values from the next node into current node and then delete next. Its that simple.

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard - take a look at [<iterator>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator), data can accessed by deferencing, an iterator can be copied to another iterator, an iterator can be advanced, but there's no iterator::erase() function. Something similar to an iterator could be used, but not a C++ STL iterator.

Comment: In general this answer is correct. Even though a pointer is a type of iterator, if you have a STL container, going in an messing with its content would remove all the encapsulation benefit of using the container in the first place. This is clearly just an exercise meant to be used without the standard containers.

Comment: That would be great and all *if* OP was using STL, but he isn't.

Comment: No, it really doesn't imply that he is using STL iterator class. You're assuming that presumably because you don't want to believe that pointers are iterators in and of themselves.

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard - I updated my answer to explain the differences between a pointer and an iterator.